# Is the org-mode manual available in .org file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to read the org-mode manual in org mode... Is there a way to download the manual in .org files?

Thanks,
Ani

Comment: Why not read the info in Emacs? M-x info<CR>, C-s org-mode<CR>

Comment: Thanks for that ! I didn't know about M-x info ! Looks like you provided me a LOT of reading material :)

Comment: I see the sources are .texi, like most emacs documentation. I poked around in Git but didn't see the conversion script.

Comment: @Demosenix, they're installed when org-mode is built from sources with `make install-info`

Comment: Next question: why it isn't available? in other words, what is the reason why .org files can't be exported to .texi files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Org-Mode manual seems to be written in texinfo format (see the doc directory in the source archive.) You can however convert e.g the HTML version to org-format using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Converting from org.texi:

```
texi2html org.texi org.html
pandoc -t org org.html -o org.org
```

You can also download my converted version [here](http://files.mpastell.com/org.org), the navigational hyperlinks don't work though so the info version is probably more useful. And here is what it looks like.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - this works really well for trying to learn since I can try things in the buffer while reading :). It would be super-awesome if the links themselves worked - but this is still pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

*Is the org-mode manual available in .org file ?*

No.

Read the org-mode manual as all other manuals in emacs : using the info mode :

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> Org Mode <kbd>RET</kbd>